# Use of @auth decorators in web2py

Tags: web2py

For many functions of my app, it requires the use of

```
@auth.requires_login()
```

Does this mean that ALL the code relating to `Auth` object defined in the model **have to** be run in order to serve the requests to an action that requires the decorator? If not, how should I re-factor the code to minimize unnecessary execution of portions of `Auth` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to check whether the user is logged in does not necessarily require that all the Auth code be run. You do have to instantiate the Auth object, but you don't have to run `auth.define_tables()` (which defines all the Auth tables). Note, if you don't define the Auth tables, the `auth.navbar()` helper function will not work as is because it tries to reference an attribute of the auth_user table. As a workaround, you could create a custom navbar function (which you might want to do anyway), or define at least that one table.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. During a request, if you **only** instantiate the Auth object, how does the decorator work? Is all the information required for the `@auth.requires_login()` collected and built into this Auth object during the instantiation?

Comment: On the other hand, during the same request without `auth.define_tables()`, why `auth.navbar()` won't work? Technically, the actual Auth tables already exist in the db at this point, so is it because `auth.define_tables()` actually loads all these table information instead of creating them for such a request? Thanks!

Comment: Once a user is logged in, their Auth user information is stored in their session. On each new request, that user information is copied from the session to the Auth object, where it can be checked by the requires_login() decorator. No database tables are required for that operation.

Comment: As part of its logic, the navbar code checks for a "username" field in the auth_user table. However, if the table hasn't been defined, that check will raise an exception. It doesn't need to actually access any data from the table -- it just needs to check the field names. It would be easy to tweak the code to avoid that check, but as is, the code will fail if the auth_user table hasn't been defined.

Comment: More generally, note there is a distinction between tables in the database (which are obviously persistent across requests), and DAL table definitions. DAL table definitions do not persist across requests -- on each request, the tables are defined so the application code knows about the database tables. `auth.define_tables()` does not create the tables on each request, but it does create DAL table definitions so the DAL can access the tables in the database.